# Do props that are functions belong in a useEffect dependencyArray?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Say I have the following code:

```
const ReactFunction = ({...props}) => {

useEffect(() => { props.function(props.value) }, [props.value])

return <input value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange} />
}

const ReactFunctionWrapper = () => {

const [value, setValue] = setState(0)
const logger = (e) => {console.log(e}

return <ReactFunction onChange={setValue} value={value} function={function} />
}
```

Should the function() prop be in the dependencyArray of the useEffect as well even though it's a function and should never change?

What exactly should be going into the dependency array?

Comment: Definitely add it to the dependencies. If that function does not change then having it as a dependency won't hurt anything. But if it does change then it's important for your `useEffect` to capture the new value of it. It will only do that if the function is listed in the dependency array.

Comment: Adding the `props.function` to the dependencies array of `useEffect` would also cause `useEffect` to trigger when `props.function` changes, even if `props.value` did not change, which might cause more invocations than needed (for example, `props.function` might unnecessarily call a remote service).

I understand capturing a ref with the previous value of `props.value` could be used to conditionally triggering the call.

But is there any practical risk in not adding `props.function` to the dependency list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, yes. Functions can appear in `useEffect`'s dependency array. Function pointers change on each refresh unless you use some cache feature to cache the function like `useMemo` or `useCallback`.

Answer (score 1):

> Should the function() prop be in the dependencyArray of the useEffect
> as well even though it's a function and should never change?

If the function doesn't references any value value from `props` or `state` or any other value derived from `props` or `state`, only then it is safe to omit that function from the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook or any other hook that has a dependency array, for example, `useCallback`.

If the function uses props or state, then it is not safe to omit it from the dependency array. You could wrap the function in `useCallback` hook to avoid creating new function reference every time the parent component re-renders.

For details on what could happen if you omit a function from useEffect's hook dependency array, see [Is it safe to omit functions from the list of dependencies?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies)

There are some functions that are guaranteed to not change and are safe to omit from the dependency array. For example: `dispatch` function returned by `useReducer` hook or state update function returned by `useState` hook. They are safe to omit but still won't hurt if you add them to the dependency array if they are used inside `useEffect` hook.

> What exactly should be going into the dependency array?

Everything in component's scope that participates in react's data flow and is used inside the `useEffect` hook's callback function. Same is true for `useMemo` and `useCallback` hooks.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to clarify that all props and state used in the useEffect should be in the dependency array, even if the prop is a function.

Comment: Yes, they should be. Even if some functions can be omitted from the dependency array, as explained in the answer, adding them to the dependency array won't do any harm.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd Parameter in `React.useEffect()` distinct when the effect is invoked. It's when the value of your 2nd Parameter changes, React runs the effect

Go checkout https://youtu.be/dpw9EHDh2bM?t=3629